Manage redeliveries in Spring Apache MQ on container
I am trying to put a spring consumer application to docker. This application listens to a queue (apache mq) and processes the message.
It has an existing logic:
If(msg.isRedelivered)    
    Do something
Else    
    Do something else

To improve performance, I also have some prefetch value as well.
tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10

I am trying to put this across 10 container instances which will be simultaneously listening to MQ.
Consider, if there are 100 messages in queue, with prefetch = 10, every consumer instance will load 10 messages in local as soon as it is started.
Now the issue is, when any of the container instance goes down and is respawned. Since, before going down the consumer already fetched 10 messages from queue, after it is up again the queue is marking the same 10 messages as “re delivery”.
This is breaking the existing logic. Is there any way, to distinguish between redelivery causes? Such as, user exceptions vs jvm dying/container respawned scenario? 
I don't want to remove redelivery in case of any user exception, but want to process prefetched messages in normal way only when container goes down.

If I lower prefetch value to 1, it works but then there is severe performance degradation.

Tried changing acknowledgement options from Auto, client, dups ok.

Session transacted flag is set to true.



Have you tried using ActiveMQ Artemis? I believe it may behave differently in this scenario using the Core JMS client. Alternatively you might try using the Qpid JMS client which communicates via AMQP.

@JustinBertram No I am using ActiveMQ classic, let me check Artemis.

@JustinBertram I dont think I can completely switch to Artemis. I assumed I can simply change the consumer to artemis and connect to AMQ classic, but I believe that is not possible.

If you're just using the plain JMS API then you should be able to switch no problem. Why can't you switch? And what exactly do you mean by, "...change the consumer to artemis and connect to AMQ classic." Wouldn't the consumer be connecting to Artemis not Classic?

@JustinBertram If our queue is classic, and consumer is artemis, can we receive the message? When I tried with same config, I was getting AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s)

The Core JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis uses the Core protocol which is not supported by ActiveMQ Classic. Therefore, you can't use the Core JMS client with ActiveMQ Classic. However, you can use the OpenWire JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Classic with ActiveMQ Artemis since Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol. In any case, my suggestion was to migrate your broker and your client to ActiveMQ Artemis to resolve your issue. I believe that if you want a different behavior here you need to use a different client.

@JustinBertram Oh migrating broker from classic to artemis will be bigger change in current context. Might need quite a few approvals. Is that the only solution?

You could try using the Qpid JMS client as I mentioned previously.

@JustinBertram I was going through documentation for Qpid as well, but I could not see any configuration which will handle redelivered messages.

I didn't mean to imply that the behavior would be configurable. My point is simply that it will be different so as to fulfill your requirements.
